# Binding ListBox to List (Collection) in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, binding

I'm learning WPF, so I'm kind of n00b in this.
I saw some examples about how to do what I want to do, but nothing exactly...

The question: I want to bind List to ListBox. I want to do it in XAML, w/o coding in code behind. How can I achieve that?

Right now I do it *that way*:

**XAML**

```
<ListBox x:Name="FileList">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=.}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**Code behind**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    // ...
    files = new List<string>();
    FileList.ItemsSource = files;
}

private void FolderBrowser_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string folder = FolderBrowser.Text;
    files.Clear();
    files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
    FileList.Items.Refresh();
}
```

But I want to get rid of `FileList.ItemsSource = files;` and `FileList.Items.Refresh();` in C# code.

Thanks

Comment: this thread may help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391746/how-can-i-data-bind-a-list-of-strings-to-a-listbox-in-wpf-wp7

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, setup the binding in your listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="FileList" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=.}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

or

```
<ListBox x:Name="FileList" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" DisplayMemberPath="."/>
```

Next, make sure "Files" is a **property** in your DataContext (or code behind).  (You can't bind to fields, only properties...)

Ideally, you'll want to make Files an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) instead of a `List<T>`, as well.  This will allow the binding to handle adding or removing elements correctly.

If you do these two things, it should just work correctly.

Comment: Thanks. Next step [for me] will be learning how to create `ObservableLis<T> : INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: Is there any way of ccuting out the <DataTemplate> part? and like going `ItemsSource="{Binding Files.PROPERTY}">?

Comment: @Nerdintraining You can use DisplayMemberPath if you're just binding a string (or something that looks right converted to a string)

Answer (score 1):

Two tricks to add to Reed's answer:

1) If all you're displaying in your list box items is a string, you can avoid the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` folderol by just setting `ListBox.DisplayMemberPath`.

2) You can set the window's `DataContext` to itself.  For instance, give the window a name of `MyWindow` and set its `DataContext` to `{Binding ElementName=MyWindow}`.  Now you can bind to any of its public properties.  (I'm pretty sure Reed's who I learned that trick from in the first place.)

Comment: Thank you. It's an interesting approach and I surely will use it.