# WP8 - Display result of WebService in grid's columns

Tags: c#, sql, web-services, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-8

Hello I have built a `WebService` that returns data from SQL:

```
    public void ListadoWebService()
    {
       // InitializeComponent();
        ServiceTours.ServiceToursClient cl = new ServiceTours.ServiceToursClient();
        cl.ListadoCompleted += new EventHandler<ListadoCompletedEventArgs>(Listado2);
        cl.ListadoAsync();
    }
    private void Listado2(object sender, ListadoCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        listB.ItemsSource = e.Result;
    }
```

Now I try to display data in `columns` of `grid`. I thought that it would work with `binding` the data to particular column as `textblock` but  I can't display the data even though the data are returned in `e.Result`.

I tried following:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listB">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}" Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Grid.Column="1" />

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

But still I have blackscreen.

Will somebody help me solve  this out please?

Comment: I Edited my post so you'd get it, I'm going to write you a more complete answer in a minute. :)

Comment: @mishan Thank you for that. I tried to do as You and MansingDodiya suggested but I got problem with this: lst.Add(new test(Id, Name)); Got this error: PhoneApp1.test does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments. I don't know how to fix, may you please help?

Comment: yes, the problem is my definition does not contain contructor, while his does. Just insert `public test(string id, string name) { Id=id; Name=name; }` in the test class. :)

Comment: I will rewrite my code so it is precise for your question. I didn't write it precisely, some of the names are just what i thought them to be and not what they really are :)

Comment: @mishan The e.Result doesn't simply offer any exact names like SecondProperty. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: So what does it offer? A list or an array of items? If you won't tell we can't help. :) Dej mi víc info :)

Comment: It does offer only when I use this: e.Result[0].Name.ToString() so I thought I can use the For loop to receive all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39284/discussion-between-mishan-and-marek)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong here, but doesn't the e.Result cease to exist as soon as the Listado2 is over?

I'm not exactly profesional, but what I would do is I would copy the stuff from result somewhere where i could preserve it longer.

**As i read the previous answer by MansinhDodiya he is basically telling you the same thing.**

1. Make a class called `Item` containing two Properties (the `public string Id{get;set;}` is a property)

   There are more ways to do it, one of them being to go to the code-behind (the .xaml.cs of that page and create the class there, other being creating a new class in the same namespace ad third, setting up new namespace and adding using).

   So in the .xaml.cs of the page create the class like that:

   ```
    class Item
    {
       public string Id {get;set;} //this is the first property i would later bind
       public string Name {get;set;} //this is the second property

       public Item(string id, string name)  // this is the contructor, every time
                                            // an instance of Item is created, this
                                            // method is called
       {
          Id = id;
          Name = name;
       }
    }
   ```
2. Make a list of these `Items` somewhere accesible

   Next to that class, inside the page class, create an instance of that list:

   ```
   List<Item> itemlist = new List<Item>();
   ```
3. copy the data into that `List<Item>` and then set that list as `itemsSource` of the listbox.

   Inside `Listado2` copy the stuff from e.Result into the `itemlist`:

   ```
   private void Listado2(object sender, ListadoCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
      ...copying from e.Result into itemList...
      listB.itemsource = itemList;
   }
   ```
4. And then change the xaml binding definition to the names of the properties - in my case:

   ```
   <ListBox x:Name="listB">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <Grid>
               ..omitted...
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Grid.Column="0" />
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="1" />
           </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   ```

Comment: Thank so much! But when I do in `Listado2` the `Id = e.Result.Id` there is no offer for `.Id` or `.Name`. I`m not sure how to fix that.

Comment: I reworked it, omitted the copying part since i don't know how the Result looks like.

Answer (score 2):

first you make one getter setter method like

```
 public class test
    {
    public string Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}

    public test(string id, string name)

    {
      Id=id;
      Name=name;
    }
     public test()

    {


    }

    than add your take one generc like 

    List<Test> lst=new List<test>();

    private void Listado2(object sender, ListadoCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
          lst.add(new test(id,name));
           listB.itemsource=lst;

        }

<ListBox x:Name="listB">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="1" />

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

visit below link also so you can get more idea

[HOw to bind data in windows phone](http://www.ginktage.com/2011/11/how-to-bind-data-to-listbox-in-windows-phone/)

[How can I data bind a list of strings to a ListBox in WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391746/how-can-i-data-bind-a-list-of-strings-to-a-listbox-in-wpf-wp7)

Hope it will work for you .....

Comment: Thank you for your interest helping me but I'm not sure how to implement your code so it would work.

Comment: `lst.Add(new test(Id, Name));` Got this error: PhoneApp1.test does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments. May I know where is the issue please?

Comment: How does your Item class look? Does it have the contructor? - the `public test(string id, string name) { Id=id; Name=name; }` method inside? - The error says: I know the class called test, but i don't have a contructor definition that says i what i should do with two string arguments.

Comment: @mishan:yes it have constructor

Comment: @MansinhDodiya I know your class has a constructor, I was asking him whether he added contructor to his code or not. :)

Comment: @MansinhDodiya + we already solved the problem on chat :) - he was doing it right in the end, the problem was the e.Result was some kind of collection of objects with five or more parameters.