# Writing .txt file on ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm to write out a text file in a ListBox, but all I'm getting is a list "BabyName". My code looks like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void FirstDecadeTopNames_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Dokumenter\Skole\6. semester\GUI\Exercises\Exercise4\WpfApplication1\04-babynames.txt", FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.Default);
        List<BabyName> babyNames = new List<BabyName>();

        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            BabyName name = new BabyName(sr.ReadLine());
            babyNames.Add(name);
            FirstDecadeTopNames.Items.Add(name);
        }
    }
}
```

I assume I'm not putting the StreamReader into my list, but I can't see where I'm doing it wrong.

**Update:**

Here's the XAML for the ListBox:

```
<ListBox Name="FirstDecadeTopNames"
         Margin="10"
         Loaded="FirstDecadeTopNames_Loaded" >
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Can you show your XAML? Did you bind the properties properly? Because `BabyName` is a class and not a single value, it won't show. Here's an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391746/how-can-i-data-bind-a-list-of-strings-to-a-listbox-in-wpf-wp7/9391815#9391815) of mine that shows how to achieve this.

Comment: Hmm... what is the name of your ListBox? There is no code that adds listbox items to your listbox, you only create a list of your BabyName objects.

Comment: @Robert: this line does it: `FirstDecadeTopNames.Items.Add(name);`.

Comment: @Abbas Oh yes of course, here's the XAML I have so far for my ListBox:

`<ListBox Name="FirstDecadeTopNames" Margin="10" Loaded="FirstDecadeTopNames_Loaded" ></ListBox>`

Answer (score 1):

I think you shoud use DisplayMemberPath property with your listBox like this:

```
<ListBox DisplayMemberPath="FieldName"...>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show us the code of where  the generic list Babyname is declared , however I don't think you need do use it anyway, instead:

```
List <string> names=new List<string>();

public void FirstDecadeTopNames_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Dokumenter\Skole\6. semester\GUI\Exercises\Exercise4\WpfApplication1\04-babynames.txt", FileMode.Open);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.Default);

    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        names.Add(sr.ReadLine());           
    }
    FirstDecadeTopNames.ItemSource=names;
}
```

Comment: When trying this out, it says the following in the while: type 'string' is not assignable to parameter type 'BabyName'?

Comment: And when using your solution it just outputs a blank list? There's a scrollbar there so I assume it's outputting all the rows of the list, but there's nothing in it.

Comment: I managed to fix it! It was in my XAML file the problem seemed to be. I just had to add a `Loaded="FirstDecadeTopNames_Loaded"` Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When you use Binding in WPF without proper path it will Display `.ToString()` of whatever you are binding. In your case it is a `list<BabyName>` so it displays only BabyName but not the value.

For example if you have

```
Class BabyName
{
  public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Then bind using `{Binding Path="Name"}`